# PHP HTTP Request (stream_context_create)

Tags: php, http

Hi I am trying to get the following to work. It is making the HTTP request because I can see it at the other end but it is not passing over the two values and parameters.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php

$url = "http://example.com/ws.php?uid=0000&pin=0000";
$fields = array(
    'target1' => $_GET['target1'],
    'target2' => $_GET['target2']);

$data = http_build_query($fields);

$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' =>  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $data,
)
));

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $data."<br />";
echo($result); 

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PHP 5.2, see PHP bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41051

#### Description:

> the http wrapper ignores 'header' option in stream_create_context( )
>   if the value is not given as a simple array; neither a string nor a
>   map (e.g. array('X-My-Header' => 'test')) will cause the additional
>   headers to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples i've seen you need a `\r\n` at the end of the header value.

```
'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
```

apart from that you will also need to provide

```
"Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
```

Comment: That is when manually crafting an HTTP request. `file_get_contents()` will detect the `$url` as an HTTP URL and format the request accordingly.